# What package do I need to make a diagram that is part-genealogy part-timeline that makes use of lines and rotated brackets?

Tags: diagrams, tikz-trees

So I am trying to replicate a certain diagram that looks to be part-genealogy of companies and part-timeline that uses lines denoting descent and rotated brackets denoting mergers.

Here is what I am trying to replicate: [image: complex diagram with brackets and geneology]

I have no idea how to start. I've been looking at various tutorials for tikz or other diagrams but I haven't quite found something that could help me make something similar to this diagram.

Perhaps someone with more experience can point me in the right direction?

Note that I'm not asking someone to make this for me, I'm asking for how could I do this myself.

Answer (score 0):

I received an answer elsewhere. Here is the solution.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, calc, positioning}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}

\begin{comment}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[align = center] (n1) {Felten \& \\ Fuillaume}; % Create first node with centred text
    \node[right = of n1] (n2) {Lahmeyer}; % Create second node next to first
    \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}] let \p1=(n1.south), \p2=(n2.south) in (\x1,\y1) -- (\x2,\y1); 
    \node[below = of $(n1)!0.5!(n2)$] (n3) {Felten \& Lahmeyer};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{comment}
    

%\begin{comment}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        % Line 1
        \node[align=center] (n1) {Prior\\ to \\ 1900:};
        \node[align=center, right=of n1] (n2) {Felten \& \\ Fuillaume}; 
        \node[right=of n2] (n3) {Lahmeyer}; 

        \node[align=center, right=of n3] (n4) {Union A.E.G.};
        
        \node[align=center, right=of n4] (n5) {Siemens \\ \& Halske};
        \node[align=center, right=of n5] (n6) {Schuckert \\ \& Co. };
        
        \node[align=center, right=of n6] (n7) {Bergmann};
        \node[align=center, right=of n7] (n8) {Kummer};
        
        % Line 2
        \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}] let \p1=(n2.south), \p2=(n3.south) in (\x1,\y1) -- (\x2,\y1); 
        \node[align=center, below=of $(n2)!0.5!(n3)$] (n11) {Felten  \& \\ Lahmeyer};

        \node[align=center, below=of n4] (n12) {A.E.G. (Gen.El.Co.)};
        \draw[decorate] (n4) -- (n12);
        
        \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}] let \p1=(n5.south), \p2=(n6.south) in (\x1,\y1) -- (\x2,\y1); 
        \node[align=center, below=of $(n5)!0.5!(n6)$] (n13) {Siemens \& \\ Halske-Schuckert};
        
        \node[align=center, below=of n7] (n14) {Bergman};
        \draw[decorate] (n7) -- (n14);
        
        \node[align=center, below=of n8] (n15) {Failed \\ in 1900};
        \draw[decorate] (n8) -- (n15);
        
        % Line 3
        \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}] let \p1=(n11.south), \p2=(n12.south) in (\x1,\y1) -- (\x2,\y1); 
        \node[align=center, below=of $(n12)!0.5!(n11)$] (n21) {A.E.G. (General Electric Co.)};
        
        \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}] let \p1=(n13.south), \p2=(n14.south) in (\x1,\y1) -- (\x2,\y1); 
        \node[align=center, below=of $(n13)!0.5!(n14)$] (n22) {Siemens \&  Halske-Schuckert};
        
        % Line 4
        \node[align=center, below = of n1] (n10) {};
        \node[align=center, below = of n10] (n20) {};
        \node[align=center, below = of n20] (n30) {By \\ 1912:};
        
        %\draw[decorate,decoration={pathreplacing}] let \p1=(n21.south), \p2=(n22.south) in (\x1,\y1) -- (\x2,\y1); 
        \node[align=center, below=of $(n21)!0.5!(n22)$] (n31) {(In close ``cooperation'' since 1908)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
%\end{comment}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, decorations.pathreplacing, calligraphy}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style={align=center, outer sep=8pt},
node distance=3cm,
]
\node (a1) at (0,0) {Prior\\to\\1900:};
\node[right of=a1] (a2) {Felten \&\\Guillaume};
\node[right of=a2] (a3) {Lahmeyer};
\draw[very thick, decorate, decoration={calligraphic brace, mirror, amplitude=6pt}] (a2.south) -| (a3.south);
\node[below=1cm] (b1) at ($(a2)!0.5!(a3)$) {Felten \& Lahmeyer};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Three text nodes and a brace]